# FatalExecutionEngineError when debugging Web Forms application

Tags: c#, webforms

I have an Web Forms application which I can build and publish in IIS server and I can start it and the application seems to work just fine but when I try to enter debug mode in Visual Studio it crashes with FatalExecutionEngineError. It crashes quite early. It enters Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax and crashes at the first method which tries to call from there. If I comment everithing in that method, it enters that method but then crashes somewhere else. I tried on 3 computers already so I guess is not the environment. Is an application I have inherited together with the sources and Visual Studio solution and everything but the original development team is gone so was no one to ask about. How to investigate such thing?